# Entity Framework - updating a large graph of entities

Tags: entity-framework

I have a large "graph" of entities that I work with in a disconnected fashion. They are POCO entities, implementing my own simple change tracking flags (IsNew, IsChanged, IsDeleted). When the time comes to save changes, I pass the entire graph back to the business tier, which does the following:-

```
context.Batches.Attach(batch);
```

where `batch` is the entity at the very top of the graph hierarchy. This has a "cascading effect" and attaches all entities in the graph, which all end up in an unchanged state. I then walk through the hierarchy setting each entity's state via the `ObjectStateManager`, based on the values of my change tracking flags.

The problem with this approach is that new entities need to be assigned unique IDs (despite being "identity" columns). I can't just leave them all as 0 otherwise the `Attach` fails with the message "An object with the same key already exists...".

Having to assign temporary, unique IDs is starting to get a bit messy, and I wondered if there was a better solution. I wondered if I could walk the graph and do an `Attach` *or* an `Add` *one entity at a time* (based on my change tracking flags), but this doesn't seem to be possible, as both methods "cascade", resulting in all child entities getting added or attached too. Is there any way around this?

I'm using EF5, ObjectContext template, if that makes a difference.

Comment: have you tried to Add instead of Attach, and then change the states of the entities. I think the problem come from the initial state when attaching. The initial sate is unchanged. So you can't have two entities of same type with the same id in the unchanged state.

Comment: @tschmit007 yeah that was my other thought. Unfortunately the graph includes quite a few relationships to "reference/lookup" entities, so I would need to set their states to "unchanged", adding to the amount of graph "walking" that I have to do. A necessary evil I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to first fetch the current entity graph from the context (with `Change Tracking` and `Proxy Generation` enabled), then walk each node and update/delete/add data based on the detached graph (using your own internal persistence status field).

Comment: So to "Add" do I simply pass the new, detached entity to context.Whatevers.Add()? What about "Delete" - can I pass the detached entity to context.Whatevers.Delete() or does it have to be done using keys (and if so, how)? And what about updates - how do I update an entity in the "current" graph from an entity in the detached graph?

Comment: It really depends on the structure of your entities, i can be of more help if you'll expose some more code. BTW, take a look at https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff

Comment: Strangely, I was just downloading GraphDiff when I saw your comment. I tried it a while ago but it was a bit buggy. They've recently fixed a few of the issues I found, so I'll try this route first and see how I get on.

Comment: It seems GraphDiff is still a little buggy. To keep the system simple I've now reverted to an "attached" approach, keeping the context alive for the duration of the user's edits. The code is much simpler (I can get rid of all my "change tracking" flags, which I commonly forgot to set), and I don't have to worry about ignoring entities marked for deletion (which I also commonly forgot to do). The only downside is that I'm burning my bridges with respect to any future chance of making the tiers distributed, but I'll take that chance.