# EF6 DbContext - Avoid re-inserting root's child record(s)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

There is an Node entity.  A Node can have many Aliases (which have an ID, and an Alias (string) properties).  Aliases should be unique based on their Alias (string) property.

I am trying to implement a method that will insert any missing Nodes to the database.  The nodes passed will include a collection of Aliases that may or may not be in the database already.  Since adding a Node (root) to the DbContext also marks all Aliases as EntityState.Added, I ended up having some of the same Aliases re-inserted into database.  Realistically, if the Alias exists in the database, the reference from the Node should just be updated to that Alias.

I started to try to tackle this problem, but am stuck because I don't know the best way to ensure that there are no duplicate Aliases in DbContext.Aliases.Local, while also setting the EntityState to EntityState.Unchaged for those Aliases that already exist in the database.

```
using (var dbContext = Application.GetDbContext()) {
    foreach (var node in nodes) {
        if (node != null) {
            var entityNode = await dbContext.Nodes.FindAsync(node.Id);

            if (entityNode == null) {
                entityNode = node is Node ? (Node)node : new Node(node);

                // Add root node.  Any navigation properties, such as 
                // aliases will be marked as EntityState.Added by default.
                dbContext.Nodes.Add(entityNode);

                for (int i = 0; i < entityNode.AliasEntities.Count; i++) {
                    var currentElement = entityNode.AliasEntities.ElementAt(i);

                    // Check cache, if null, check database for the Alias
                    var dbAliasEntity = dbContext.Aliases.FirstOrDefaultCache(x => x.Alias == currentElement.Alias);

                    // If Alias already exists in the database, mark it as Unchanged.
                    if (dbAliasEntity != null) {
                        currentElement = dbAliasEntity;
                        dbContext.Entry(currentElement).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The above code currently throws the following Exception:

> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of
>   type 'NWatch.Entities.NWatchAlias' have the same primary key value.
>   Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that
>   database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the
>   database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer
>   for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the
>   'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or
>   'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration. What
>   modifications do I need to make in order to ensure that only Aliases
>   that aren't already in the database are inserted?

Comment: I suspect you are not properly working with the nodes and aliases via the entity framework. Make sure you are attaching those nodes to the db context, because otherwise the EF already does this, if it is properly configured.

Comment: Attaching a Node marks its State as unchanged.  These Nodes passed in may or may not be in the database already (it's an unknown).  It's also possible that the node may exist in the database, but one of its Aliases doesn't.

Comment: ahh so you are working in a large detached scenario? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17696858/703644) is probably your answer then